# ZIP Code Tabulation Area (ZCTA) Relationship with Census Blocks?

Tags: census

The US Census provides a relationship file to connect ZIP Code Tabulation Areas (ZCTAs) with counties, county subdivisions, places, census tracts, congressional districts, and MSAs, found here: `https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/zcta_rel_download.html`

I'm looking for this same type of file, but linking ZCTAs to block tracts (preferred) or block groups.

Does anyone know if the Census or a third-party has published such a document?

Thanks in advance!

Mo

Comment: Block groups and blocks are both beneath tracts in the census geography hierarchy, and therefore the first 11 digits of each GEOID will tell you which census tract they belong to. I suggest you use that info to join the zip code information to your block or block group data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `R`, you can use [`totalcensus`](https://github.com/GL-Li/totalcensus) package to generate the file.